# Missing symbols __Unwind_resume and __assert_fail when trying to run jited code in llvm

Tags: llvm, jit, llvm-clang

We are trying to adapt the clang-llvm interpreter code [here](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/examples/clang-interpreter/) to run some c++ code that uses stl  vector and c++ string among other things. This resulted in a number of unresolved symbols, and after eliminating a bunch of them, we are still stuck with __Unwind_resume and __assert_fail

I would really appreciate any help on resolving this.

Note: we were having problem with includes in the code that needed to be jitted so we ran clang++ to preprocess it and the output of that is a single c++ file with no dependency on local includes. Not sure if that has introduced some problems.

Note2: This is on Ubuntu 12.01 and we tried compiling clang interpreter with both clang+llvm 3.1 and with gcc 4.6.3